# Can I check a subcommand can be run in Python Click before checking the options

Tags: python, python-click

I use python click to create a CLI with subcomands for my app. I've got a code like this:

```
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command(debug)
@@click.option('--debug/--no-debug', default=False)
def sub1():
    # code doing stuff on a git repo

@cli.command()
@click.option('--yes', type=bool, default=False)
def sub2(yes):
    # code doing other stuff on the git repo

@cli.command()
@click.option('--yes', type=bool, default=False)
def sub3(yes):
    # code doing last stuff on git repo
```

My problem is that, followong the above code, the only allowed order for the commands is `cli sub1 -> cli sub2 -> cli sub3`. That's related to the git code it's running in the background (e.g. a commit needs to make a branch before).

What I'd like to do is to define a command such as

```
def check_2():
    # checking cli sub1 was run.
```

and run it at the begining of `cli sub2` to check that `cli sub1` ran before (this function determines the state "`cli sub1` was run before" by looking at the git repo state).

My problem is that I want to run it **before** to parse the options (I defined my own callback to prompt the input if missing). I don't want the user to enter its options and get the error afterwards.

An idea?

Comment: *I want to run it before*  It is not clear to me what exactly you are trying to get done.  It seems you want to run some code before prompting the user for something?  If my interpretation is correct, please show this prompting code.  As of now this question seems unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what I needed in the click documentation.

Here is my solution with debug handling.

```
@click.group()
@click.option("--debug/--no-debug", default=False, envvar="GIPP_DEBUG")
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, debug):
    try:
        subcommand = ctx.invoked_subcommand
        validate_subcommand(subcommand)
    except Exception as e:
        if debug:
            raise
        else:
            sys.exit(f"Error: {e}")

@cli.command()
def sub1():
    # code doing stuff on a git repo

...
```